# How can I make sure my financial advisor has a good track of success?

Tags: financial-advisor

I will be exiting my main business real soon and projecting that in 2 years time I will also exit my other businesses or at least sell them at whatever someone is willing to pay.

This will net me quite a hefty start in life (I am 20). Being this young, altough I think of myself as pretty smart, still shows a lack of experience in many areas, financials being one.

As such:

How can I verify that an EU financial advisor has a proven track record, can he show it?

Comment: See Risk Profiling & Manager Selection here: https://www.suggestus.com/

Comment: Check if his name has "index" in it. :-)